# why is some space is remaining after swipe left and right in Listview

Tags: android, listview

I swipe both side in Listview it successfully done but when when i swipe any side some space is vacant I can't find why is space is renaming: -

[image]

[image]

Space is renaming after secondary  layout. Here is my child layout:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.octalsoftaware.archi.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/whitecolor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_charge"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/red_color"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/whitecolor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_settingname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lee Alexender"
                android:textColor="@color/lightblack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/chargecircle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/qicircle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cameracircle" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</com.octalsoftaware.archi.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these lines in your `LinearLayout`

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `FrameLayout` as a direct child of `SwipeLayout`.
2. Add `attribute android:layout_gravity="right"` to `delete_layout`
3. Add `attribute android:layout_gravity="left"` to `left_layout`

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.octalsoftaware.archi.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/whitecolor">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/delete_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red_color"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_charge"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red_color"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_delete"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/forbidden" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/delete"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/whitecolor"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:visibility="visible">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_arrow"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_settingname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lee Alexender"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightblack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/chargecircle" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/qicircle" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/cameracircle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</com.octalsoftaware.archi.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```